# Get label from selector in Cypress

Tags: jquery, cypress

Using `cypress`, how do you obtain the label for an input field given a selector for the input field?

Initially I was thinking providing the input selector into a "label for selector" with a string template, however you need to provide the **id** of the input field, so naturally it does not work.

```
`label[for="${selector}"]`
```

Further I have attempted to `invoke` jquery method `attr` with argument `id` on yielded field, however invoke() only returns a chainable cypress wrapper so it will also not work as well.

```
const field= cy.get(selector);
field.label = () => field.closest(`label[for="${field.invoke("attr","id")}"]`);
return field
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution. had to use .then()

```
const field= cy.get(selector);
field.label = () => field.invoke("attr","id").then(($id) => {
    return field.get(`label[for="${$id}"]`);
})
return field;
```